# When is a closing </li> not optional?

Tags: html

[W3 says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html):

> An `li` element’s end tag may be omitted if the `li` element is immediately followed by another `li` element or if there is no more content in the parent element.

But this:

```
<ol>
    <li>one
    <li>two
    <li>three
        <ol>
            <li>three.one
            <li>three.two
        </ol>
    <li>four
</ol>
```

Appears to [render fine](http://jsfiddle.net/yt94J/).

I don't know if four's `li` is considered to "immediately follow" three's `li` or not because there's an `ol` inbetween. The spec isn't really clear -- technically the text "one" represents a TextNode so two's `li` doesn't really immediately follow either.

Is there *actually* any scenario where a closing `</li>` is necessary?

I've only got Chrome and Firefox installed, but they both render the above how I would expect.

As far as I'm aware, the only legal direct children of `ul` and `ol` are `li` so there *can't* be any ambiguity, right?

Comment: You seem to confuse tags with elements. The `ol` element is inside the `li` element.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Right, and if you omit the closing `</li>`s you can't *not* put everything into one `<li>` element or another *unless* the content precedes the *first* `<li>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, what W3C is saying is

> An `li` element’s end tag is *mandatory* if the `li` element is immediately followed by *something else than* another `li` element or if there *is more* content in the parent element.

How is this possible? `li` Elements can [only occur](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context) within `ol`s, `ul`s and `menu`s.
But `ol`s und `ul`s allow only `li`s as their children.

What about `menu`? It [allows flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/menu.html#menu) too. So there you have it:

```
<menu>
    <li>foo</li> <!-- mandatory -->
    <a href="//example.com">bar</a>
</menu>

<menu>
    <li>foo</li> <!-- mandatory -->
    Hello, I am text content!
</menu>
```

When you see the examples it is pretty obvious that omitting the end tag would give the parser no chance to determine where the `li` ends.

---

Edit: as @BoltClock points out below, `script` and `template` elements are now allowed too:

```
<ul> <!-- or ol or menu -->
    <li>foo</li> <!-- mandatory -->
    <script></script>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also, apparently `li` is no longer the only legal child of `ul` and `ol` - `script` and `template` may appear as well.

Comment: @BoltClock I wasn't aware of that. Any references?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element. Validators (.w3.org and Nu) seem to agree. Strangely, /html-markup/ hasn't been updated. Could it be a recent change?

Comment: Oh, looks like html-markup is completely obsolete: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/Overview.html#abstract

Comment: Wow. Looks like it's been that way for over a *year* now. It would be nice if that notice appeared on every page and not just the front page.

Comment: Also, looks like the `menu` element has been removed. WHATWG still has it, though. Edit: ah, [it has returned in HTML5.1](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element)

Comment: Your example is incorrect. [`LI`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) element can be inside [`MENU`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element) only if `MENU` has `type` attribute set to `toolbar`. In your example `type` attribute is ommited, so it uses the default `popup` value what disallows putting `LI` elements inside as long as the state is not set to `toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Closing `</li>` is not optional when the `LI` it closes is followed by any element other than `LI`.

Comment: Dude, what other element would that be? I stated in the question that (I thought) the only valid children were `li`s themselves.

Comment: Any [script supporting element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) ([`TEMPLATE`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-template-element) or [`SCRIPT`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element)) inside `OL` element, `UL` element or `MENU` element with `type` attribute set to `toolbar`.